# Performance issue on query with math calculations

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

This my query with its performance (slow_query_log):

```
SELECT j.`offer_id`, o.`offer_name`, j.`success_rate`
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        t.`offer_id`,
        (
            SUM(CASE WHEN `offer_id` = t.`offer_id` AND `sales_status` = 'SUCCESS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*)
        ) AS `success_rate`
    FROM `tblSales` AS t
    WHERE   DATE(t.`sales_time`) = CURDATE()  
    GROUP BY t.`offer_id`               
    ORDER BY `success_rate` DESC
) AS j
LEFT JOIN `tblOffers` AS o
    ON j.`offer_id` = o.`offer_id`
LIMIT 5;

# Time: 180113 18:51:19
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]  Id:    71
# Query_time: 10.472599  Lock_time: 0.001000 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1156134
```

Here, `tblOffers` have all the OFFERS listed. And the `tblSales` contains all the sales. What am trying to find out is the top selling offers, based on the success rate (ie. those sales which are SUCCESS).

The query works fine and provides the output I needed. But it appears to be that its a bit slower.

`offer_id` and `sales_status` are already indexed in the `tblSales`. So do you have any suggestion on improving the inner query (where it calculates the success rate) so that performance can be improved? I have been playing with the math for more than 2hrs. But couldn't get a better way.

Btw, `tblSales` has lots of data. It contains those sales which are SUCCESSFUL, FAILED, PENDING, etc.

Thank you

---

**EDIT**

As you requested am including the table design also(only relevant fields are included):

```
tblSales
`sales_id`          bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`offer_id`          bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   
`sales_time`        DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0000-00-00 00:00:00',   
`sales_status`      ENUM('WAITING', 'SUCCESS', 'FAILED', 'CANCELLED') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'WAITING',
PRIMARY KEY (`sales_id`),
KEY (`offer_id`),
KEY (`sales_status`)
```

There are some other fields also in this table, that holds some other info. Amount, user_id, etc. which are not relevant for my question.

Comment: Please post your table schema and results of `EXPLAIN` query so we can provide you better solution. Also a link to sqlfiddle will be more helpful.

Comment: Incidentally, LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: And when would `offer_id` not equal t.`offer_id` !?! They're the same thing !?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here, tblOffers have all the OFFERS listed. And the tblSales contains all the sales. What am trying to find out is the top selling offers, based on the success rate (ie. those sales which are SUCCESS).

Approach this with a simple `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT s.offer_id, o.offer_name,
       AVG(s.sales_status = 'SUCCESS') as success_rate
FROM tblSales s JOIN
     tblOffers o
     ON o.offer_id = s.offer_id
WHERE s.sales_time >= CURDATE() AND
      s.sales_time < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY s.offer_id, o.offer_name              
ORDER BY success_rate DESC;
```

Notes:

- The use of date arithmetic allows the query to make use of an index on `tblSales(sales_time)` -- or better yet `tblSales(salesTime, offer_id, sales_status)`.
- The arithmetic for `success_rate` has been simplified -- although this has minimal impact on performance.
- I added `offer_name` to the `GROUP BY`.  If you are learning SQL, you should always have all the unaggregated keys in the `GROUP BY` clause.
- A `LEFT JOIN` is only needed if you have offers in `tblSales` which are not in `tblOffers`.  I am guessing you have proper foreign key relationships defined, and this is not the case.

Comment: Optimizing for `LIMIT 5` is also needed.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this with adding an INDEX to the `sales_time` field and it seems to be better now. But just a doubt, am already having a `primary_key=sales_id`, then indexed fields `offer_id`, `sales_status`, and now `sales_times`. But this `tblSales` will get new records added very often. I mean within a minute, maybe 100s to 1000s of records. So would all these indexed fields make it difficult for the insertion and updation of records in this table? At the moment, I have around `1156134` rows in this table, and is growing.

Comment: @VppMan . . . Indexes add some overhead to updates and inserts.  If the rate is one modification per minute, you have nothing to worry about (if it is a 100 per second, then you can start worrying).

Answer (score 1):

Numerous 'problems', *none* of which involve "math".

`JOINs` make things difficult.  `LEFT JOIN` says "I don't care whether the row exists in the 'right' table.  (I suspect you don't need `LEFT`??)  But it also says "There may be multiple rows in the right table.  Based on the column names, I will *guess* that there is only one `offer_name` for each `offer_id`.  If this is correct, then here my first recommendation.  (This will convince the Optimizer that there is no issue with the `JOIN`.)  Change from

```
SELECT ..., o.offer_name, ...
    LEFT JOIN  `tblOffers` AS o  ON j.`offer_id` = o.`offer_id`
    ...
```

to

```
SELECT ...,
        ( SELECT offer_name FROM tbloffers WHERE offer_id j.offer_id
        ) AS offer_name, ...
```

It also gets rid of a *bug* wherein you are assuming that the inner `ORDER BY` will be preserved for the `LIMIT`.  This used to be the case, but in newer versions of MariaDB / MySQL, it is *not*.  The `ORDER BY` in a "derived table" (your subquery) is now *ignored*.

2 down, a few more to go.

"Don't hide an indexed column in a function."  I am referring to `DATE(t.sales_time) = CURDATE()`.  Assuming you have no `sales_time` values for the 'future', then that test can be changed to `t.sales_time >= CURDATE()`.  If you really need to restrict to just today, then do this:

```
  AND sales_time >= CURDATE()
  AND sales_time  < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

The `ORDER BY` and the `LIMIT` should usually be put together.  In your case, you may as well add the `LIMIT` to the "derived table", thereby leading to only 5 rows for the outer query to work with.  But...  There is still the question of getting them sorted correctly.  So change from

```
 SELECT ...
     FROM ( SELECT ...
               ORDER BY ... )
     LIMIT ...
```

to

```
 SELECT ...
     FROM ( SELECT ...
               ORDER BY ...
               LIMIT 5 )    -- trim sooner
     ORDER BY ...           -- deal with the loss of ordering from derived table
```

Rolling it all together, I have

```
SELECT  j.`offer_id`, 
        ( SELECT  offer_name
            FROM  tbloffers
            WHERE  offer_id = j.offer_id 
        ) AS offer_name,
        j.`success_rate`
    FROM  
        ( SELECT  t.`offer_id`,
                  AVG(t.sales_status = 'SUCCESS') AS `success_rate`
            FROM  `tblSales` AS t
            WHERE  t.sales_time >= CURDATE()
            GROUP BY  t.`offer_id`
            ORDER BY  `success_rate` DESC
            LIMIT  5 
        ) AS j
    ORDER BY  `success_rate` DESC;
```

(I took the liberty of shortening the `SUM(...)` in two ways.)

Now for the indexes...

`tblSales` needs at least `(sales_time)`, but let's go for a "covering" (with `sales_time` specifically first):

```
INDEX(sales_time, sales_status, order_id)
```

If `tbloffers` has `PRIMARY KEY(offer_id)`, then no further index is worth adding.  Else, add this covering index (in this order):

```
INDEX(offer_id, offer_name)
```

(Apologies to other Answerers; I stole some of your ideas.)

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be working fine. But a small typo in your code is `t.sales_status` instead of `s.sales_status`. Probably you got mixed up with the letter I used for the alias name. And thanks for the tip on the `limit`

Comment: t.sales_status fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on not much information that you have provided (i mean table schema) you could try the following.

```
SELECT `o`.`offer_id`, `o`.`offer_name`, SUM(CASE WHEN `t`.`sales_status` = 'SUCCESS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `success_rate`
FROM `tblOffers` `o`
INNER JOIN `tblSales` `t`
ON `o`.`offer_id` = `t`.`offer_id`
WHERE DATE(`t`.`sales_time`) = CURDATE()  
GROUP BY `o`.`offer_id`               
ORDER BY `success_rate` DESC
LIMIT 0,5;
```

You can find a sample of this query in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3084e5/1) example

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your schema, the lowest hanging fruit I see is this part....

```
WHERE   DATE(t.`sales_time`) = CURDATE()
```

Try changing that to something that looks like

```
Where t.sales_time >= @12-midnight-of-current-date and t.sales_time <= @23:59:59-of-current-date
```

Comment: Two answers show a 'better' way to do that datetime range.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Goose